# Day off or off day?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between 'day off' and 'off day'? What I found is 'day off' means a holiday when you are not working, while 'off day' is the day when you do not work up to the mark. Can anyone put more light on this?

Comment: You mean, "Can anyone _shed_ more light on this?"

Comment: It is perfectly valid to say: "I'm having an off day, so I'll take the day off."

Comment: @BryceWagner but not as likely to say that you are having a day off, so it is an off day. "A bad day of fishing is better than a good day working."

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you are correct, the word "off" like many small english words has a large number of meanings, some of them are even opposites.

"day off" meaning "not present this day"
Either scheduled break or due to dishonesty, illness or other emergency.

off(adverb) "away from a place"

"off day" meaning "not performing well this day"

off(adjective) "not up to standard; not so good or satisfactory as usual; inferior or subnormal"

Comment: 'due to dishonesty'? Can you expand on that one, I'm not sure I get your meaning.

Comment: dishonesty eg: feigning illness to get a day off.  (see also Ferris Bueller's Day Off)

Comment: Oh I see, I think I was thrown by it coming before sickness in your list. I'm not a manager so I don't think about people fibbing if they call in sick!

Comment: I had to put sickness next to emergency,

Comment: "off" can also mean unfresh - beginning to be rotten, rancid, or spoiled (of food, etc).  *"I think the milk has gone off, it doesn't quite smell right."*

Comment: @J... I would just say _"I think the milk has gone bad; it smells off."_ I don't think _gone off_ is used much, but that may be due to regional differences.

Comment: @JedSchaaf It's a common expression in Br.E - perhaps less so elsewhere?

Comment: @J... In my experience (Am.E.) _go off_ is used in reference to either a firearm accidentally or unexpectedly firing or someone becoming suddenly angry. It sounds odd to me being used to refer to rancid milk.

Comment: When someone asks if I am off, I always say, "I took a shower this morning...?"

Comment: @JedSchaaf In BrE, we might say *food* has *gone bad* or *gone off*; but we would not say *milk* (or any liquid) has *gone bad* - for that we would always use *gone off*.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, a ***day off*** is a [*holiday* for someone or a *day that they have taken off*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/day-off):

> 1. a day on which somebody usually and regularly does not have to work
> 2. a day on which somebody is allowed not to come into work

An ***off day*** for someone can mean same as day off, or that they are having a *[bad day at work](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-day)*:

> 1. informal if somebody has an off day, they do not perform as well as usual.
> 2. [US] a day when people do not go to work.

Comment: Both meanings have in common the idea that something is not behaving the way it usually behaves.

Comment: I don't think of a day off as a holiday (day that everyone has off) but instead as a vacation day or comp day.

Comment: I feel like for "off day" there would be a difference in the emphasis depending if one meant it as a day off, or as a bad day. an "OFF day" would be a day off. an "off DAY" would be a bad day.

Comment: @nocomprende In the UK, "holiday" generally means "vacation" (unless used specifically to refer to a "public holiday" or "bank holiday") - we tend not to use the word "vacation".

Comment: @TrevorD wouldn't it be less confusing to have two different words for two different concepts? Then you wouldn't need to qualify the word 'holiday' with another word to change its meaning.

Comment: @nocomprende It may be - but I don't control how English develops!

Comment: @TrevorD you can decide not to persist in confusing usages. For example, I stopped calling the US "America" when someone pointed out that the people in the *other* 20 nations in North, Central and South America are *Americans* too. I never say "American" anymore.

Comment: @nocomprende Not sure what your point is - where have I called the US "America"? It's actually something I try to avoid doing, because I'm well aware of the differences - especially as my brother & family live in Canada. Maybe you should be preaching to Obama & everyone else in the USA who cries out "God bless **America**".

Comment: Incidentally, usage of the word 'holiday' in the UK very rarely causes any misunderstanding or confusion amongst British people.

Comment: @TrevorD you said you don't control how language develops. But you do. Use words in a non-confusing way and you are exerting all the control that you have available. It is like voting. My America thing was preceded by the words "For example", meaning, it was relevant, not that you were doing it. British people communicate with people outside Britain, and usages that they have no trouble with can cause trouble elsewhere. So a simple and clear use of language is advised.

Comment: @nocomprende I'm not disputing anything you've said there. But I would suggest (a) that British people are more aware of differences between British & US uses of English, than are many US residents; (2) US people consistently refer to themselves as 'American' and use both 'American' & 'America' to refer solely to the USA.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the existing answers may be a little narrow, so I'll expand here. These phrases do not need to be confined to lacking presence at work, school, etc.

"**Day off**" may refer to any non-work related task or a situation.

> I have a day off of parenting because my kid's away at camp.
>
> My upstairs neighbor is on vacation so I have a day off from having to listen to them stomping around.

---

"**Off day**" needs certain other cues when used as the different definitions. To be used similarly to "*day off*", it is typically used in future tense, to describe a date, or else has the situation explicitly followed by the location/task/experience.

> July 4th was an off day.
>
> Friday is an off day.
>
> I went to the beach this afternoon because today is an off day at work.

<sub>Reference: [[1]](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-day) Corroboration: [[2]](http://www.chicagotribune.com/sports/baseball/cubs/ct-anthony-rizzo-offday-bits-cubs-spt-0514-20160513-story.html)[[3]](https://sports.vice.com/en_us/show/off-day)</sub>

For "**off day**" to be used as a description of performance, emotion, or wellbeing, it's typically used in a more generic sense, used with "have", or else explicitly stated as pertaining to the speaker.

> Today's just sort of an off day.
>
> I was having a total off day yesterday.
>
> Monday was such an off day for me.

---

Both of these phrases may also be used with other time indicators.

> Christmas and New Years are both on weekends so to meet the required vacation days, they just gave us the whole **week off**!
>
> It's just been an **off month** for me -- nothing's gone right for weeks!

Comment: To me, "off day" is about an experience, so it can never describe the future, and not be something chosen (or desired), rather like the word 'pain'.

Comment: To be used the same as "day off", you can use it in any tense. Otherwise, I agree with you.

Comment: I disagree with your second block of meanings (at least in BrE). Can you provide some substantiation of using "off day" to mean "day off", i.e. A day in which one does not go to work?

Comment: @TrevorD I'd say it's not common but I have personally used it. (AmE here)

Comment: You having used it doesn't mean that it's correct usage &mdash; that's why this site prefers answers with third-party substantiation.

Comment: @TrevorD Another answerer included it, and anyone I asked also said they'd use it.

Comment: 1. I can't see it included in another answer.  2. Neither the fact that "answerer included it" nor that "anyone I asked also said they'd use it" constitutes "third-party substantiation" within the context of this site. Third-party substantiation = cited authoritative sources.

Comment: @TrevorD there's only two other answers. It's not hard to find the other that mentions it. I will look for citations for you later, but language is an oral tradition. What you hear *is* what's in use. No need to get mean about it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit in that answer when I checked. It's not me being 'mean'. I suggest you look in more detail at the 'rules', expectations & purpose of this site.

Comment: @TrevorD The explanation given by the other answerer was actually quoted from [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-day). They are known to source outside databases for usage and frequency yet retain full editorial control over entries. This means that, unlike Urban Dictionary, any new entry must be corroborated before inclusion.

Comment: @TrevorD Here is a usage example in both the body and headline of an article in the Chicago Tribune: http://www.chicagotribune.com/sports/baseball/cubs/ct-anthony-rizzo-offday-bits-cubs-spt-0514-20160513-story.html

Comment: @TrevorD Sorry, meant to append this but got called away during the 5-minute window...

Vice Sports uses the standalone phrase as a title for an entire series: https://sports.vice.com/en_us/show/off-day

Comment: I'm not disputing references from other answers.  I'm suggesting that **your** answer should be independent of other answers and should contain references to support your contentions.  Also, I suggest that you should *amend your answer to include your references*, rather than just cite them in comments. Comments can get tidied up & deleted in time - but the Answers remain.

Comment: I came across the Collins reference independently and recognized the definition. I wanted to be sure these submissions would pass muster with critics before conducting multiple citation edits. Don't get me wrong -- I do appreciate the push to get some supporting evidence besides my own experience as a native speaker, but I do think you could go about it a little more softly next time? I *am* still pretty new to this community, especially as anything but a lurker via clickthroughs on the sidebar. :)

Comment: Apologies if I took the wrong tone. I noted your rep. is at 138 and assumed from that that you had been here a little while.

Comment: @TrevorD I got 100 for high ranking on another site on the network. :P